# Why pcre regex is much faster than c++11 regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, pcre

Some sample code. This is the c++11 part using cregex_iterator:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
regex re("<option[\\s]value[\\s]*=[\\s]*\"([^\">]*)\"[\\s]*[^>]*>", regex::icase);
int found = 0;
for (std::cregex_iterator i = std::cregex_iterator(input, input + input_length, re);
i != std::cregex_iterator();
    ++i)
{
    found++;
    if (found < 10000) continue;
    break;
}
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

This is the pcre part. The regexp is all the same.

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin4 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
const char *pError = NULL;
int errOffset;
int options = PCRE_MULTILINE | PCRE_CASELESS;
const char* regexp = "<option[\\s]value[\\s]*=[\\s]*\"([^\">]*)\"[\\s]*[^>]*>";
pcre* pPcre = pcre_compile(regexp, options, &pError, &errOffset, 0);                
int offset = 0;
int matches = -1;
int pMatches[6];
while (offset < input_length)
{
    matches = pcre_exec(pPcre,NULL, input, input_length, offset,0, pMatches,6); 
    if (matches >= 1)
    {
        found++;
        offset = pMatches[1];
        if (found < 10000) continue;
        break;  // find match
    }
    else
        offset = input_length;
}

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end4 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

The result shows pcre is 100 times faster than c++11. I found some vector copy and resize in c++11 implementation. Are there some other reasons?

Comment: I don't know the answer in any case, but what compiler / standard library are you using?

Comment: Also the fact that you are not using the results might have an effect.

Comment: I put my money on libstdc++, it managed to stay for several years with a regex implementation that segfaulted on valid regexes, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that the current implementation is "just" suboptimal in efficiency.

Comment: What happens if you use `std::regex_constants::optimize`?

Comment: Why are you surprised that two unrelated regex implementations don't have the same performance? Heck, you can still make PCRE faster by using its JIT feature.

Comment: They have different syntax, so their implementations are different.

Comment: What's your `input`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCRE benefits from some optimizations known as *start-up optimizations* which are configured to be enabled by default. These optimizations include:

1. A subject pre-scan for unanchored patterns (if a *starting* point is
   not found engine doesn't even bother to go through matching
   process.)
2. Studying pattern to ensure that minimum length of subject is not shorter than pattern itself
3. Auto-possessification
4. Fast failure (if a *specific* point is
   not found engine doesn't even bother to go through matching
   process.)

### Superficial pattern analyzing:

```
<option             # Subject pre-scan applied (unachored pattern)
    [\\s]
    value
    [\\s]*          # Auto-possessification applied (translates to \s*+)
    =
    [\\s]*          # //
    \"([^\">]*)\"   
    [\\s]*          # //
    [^>]*
>                   # Min length (17 chars) check of subject string applied
```

Furthermore, if input string doesn't have a special character like `>`, a fast failure is supposed to be thrown. You should know that performance can depend on input string heavily as well.

Run below pattern:

```
(*NO_AUTO_POSSESS)(*NO_START_OPT)<option[\s]value[\s]*=[\s]*\"([^\">]*)\"[\s]*[^>]*>
```

over this input string (watch that period):

```
<option value                                                                 .
```

and compare result ([Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/Eiwvpw/1)).

Comment: When in doubt, use `pcretest` :) In this case, without studying the pattern (as in OP's code), it says: `First char = '<' Need char = '>'`. If you add the study option, you'll get: `First char = '<' Need char = '>' Subject length lower bound = 17 No starting char list`