# C++ regex_search vs regex matching in perl

Tags: c++, regex, perl

I have a log file, which consists of 400k log lines.
I found out, that my c++ code is very slow in comparison to perl code. 
So I made a simple iteration over my log file and used regex of c++ and of perl. Perl scripts executes very fast while on the other hand c++ is taking time.

In c++ i have in use `#include<regex>` library. Whereas in perl, regex can be used directly. 
How can I make c++ code as efficient as perl? Since perl's implementation is by C only.

```
regex log_line("(\\d{1,2}\\/[A-Za-z]{3}\\/\\d{1,4}):(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}).*?\".*?[\\s]+(.*?)[\\s\?].*?\"[\\s]+([\\d]{3})[\\s]+(\\d+)[\\s]+\"(.*?)\"[\\s]+\"(.*?)\"[\\s]+(\\d+)");
string line;
int count =0;
smatch match;
while(getline(logFileHandle, line){
    if(regex_search(line , match , log_line)==true){
    count++
}


open(N==LOG_FILE,"<$log_file_location");
        my $count=0;
        while($thisLine = <=LOG_FILE>){
            if((($datePart, $time, $requestUrl, $status, $bytesDelivered, $httpReferer, $httpUserAgent, $requestReceived) = $thisLine =~ /(\d{1,2}\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/\d{1,4}):(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}).*?\".*?[\s]+(.*?)[\s\?].*?\"[\s]+([\d]{3})[\s]+(\d+)[\s]+\"(.*?)\"[\s]+\"(.*?)\"[\s]+(\d+)/o) == 8){
                $count++;
            }
        }
```

I'm afraid, if my question is not in the right format or something is missing let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT 1**
So I used *chrono* library in c++ to find out the time taken. Below is the output result. I took a sample of log file to make things easy. 
Simply reading the log file and counting no. of lines takes 57 ms. When regex_search is used it takes a whopping 2462 ms for the same sample log file.

```
No of Lines27399
With regex + logfileRead
Time taken by function: 2462 milliseconds
No of Lines27399
With just simple logfileRead
Time taken by function: 57 milliseconds
```

Comment: Most C++ standard library regex implementations are not known for their speed. Stick with Perl, or use a more optimized/better performing C++ regex library.

Comment: Are you compiling C++ with optimizations enabled? If you're matching the entire log line, try using `regex_match` instead of `regex_search`.

Comment: Do you know any optimized regex library? @Shawn
No, I am just compiling `g++ log.cpp` @Praetorian Okay, let me try. But still, if I had to use regex_search only, is there any way to perform at par with perl?

Comment: @Praetorian If the bottleneck is the regexp matching, optimizing his code is not likely to make too much difference.

Comment: Your C++ code isn't valid.

Comment: @NetMage with due respect sir, this is just a part of the code to make things crisp and clear, and the code is running fine. :D

Comment: Can you explain where the close brace for the `if` is in your sample code? What about the "statement" `count++` that doesn't end in a semicolon? Did you copy and paste it into a C++ compiler?

Comment: Are you able to change the regex engine you're using? Something like [pcrecpp](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrecpp.html) which implements PCRE for C++ might make a difference. Keep in mind this type of data crunching is what Perl was built for, so matching Perl's speed vs making your C++ regex faster may be two different goals. Edit: this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481811/why-pcre-regex-is-much-faster-than-c11-regex) may add some perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a code generator tool like [re2c](http://re2c.org) or [ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) to compile your regular expression into C/C++ code (which can be optimized by the compiler).

Alternatively, [Boost.Regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) -- which was the basis for std::regex -- may be faster than your std::regex implementation.

Also, the bottleneck might be I/O rather than regular expressions.  [Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python?rq=1)

Comment: Okay, I need to look up on re2c or ragel tool.
Kindly look in my edit, I have shared the time taken to read file and time taken to read and use regex.
But the point is, I don't think reading the log file is a bottleneck here. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On using boost::regex c++ code flies like a jet. 
The std::regex is not optimised and made for performance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.